# Updating default-kieserver capabilities in RHPAM business central V7.1.1.GA

Tags: kie-server

I want to enable Process capability in RHPAM V7.1.1.GA in kie-server as specified in the screen shot.
Checked document of RHPAM but not able to find.
Actually i am trying to create a workflow and tried to deploy it. But not able to initiate the new instance. Getting no deployment found.
Then i compared with another business central with workflows deployed and saw the process check box selected is missing.
Tried to figure out through documentation but not able find any answer.
Any suggestion or reference...will be really helpful.
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4X7Sm.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjdRO.jpg)

Actually i am trying to create a workflow and tried to deploy it. But not able to initiate the new instance. Getting no deployment found.
Then i compared with another business central with workflows deployed and saw the process check box selected is missing.
Tried to figure out through documentation but not able find any answer.
I need the reference how to enable the process checkbox in kie-server capabilities screen in business central.
Following are from my standalone-full.xml

```
<system-properties>
<property name="org.kie.demo" value="false"/>
<property name="org.kie.server.repo" value="${jboss.server.data.dir}"/>
<property name="org.kie.example" value="true"/>
<property name="org.jbpm.server.ext.disabled" value="true"/>
 <property name="org.kie.task.insecure" value="true"/>
<property name="org.kie.server.location" value="http://localhost:8080/kie-    server/services/rest/server"/>
 <property name="org.kie.server.controller" value="http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller"/>
<property name="org.kie.server.controller.user" value="XXXXX"/>
<property name="org.kie.server.controller.pwd" value="XXXXX"/>
<property name="org.kie.server.user" value="XXXXX"/>
<property name="org.kie.server.pwd" value="XXXXX"/>
<property name="org.kie.server.id" value="default-kieserver"/>
<property name="org.kie.server.persistence.ds" value="java:jboss/datasources/JbpmDS"/>
<property name="org.kie.server.persistence.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
<property name="jboss.as.management.blocking.timeout" value="10000"/>
<property name="org.jbpm.designer.perspective" value="full"/>
<property name="designerdataobjects" value="false"/>
<property name="org.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment" value="false"/>
<property name="kie.maven.settings.custom" value="/XXXXX/XXXXX/.m2/settings.xml"/>
<property name="XXXXXXXXXXXX" value="false"/>
```